# Schema dump with pre-existing MySQL database results in NoMethodError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, schema

I've been trying to do a schema dump with a new Rails project using an existing MySQL database. Here's my setup in my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: username_example
  password: password_example
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: databasename
```

I added the following gems to my Gemfile and bundled:

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
```

After using the command `rake db:schema:dump` I get the following error in my schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

# Could not dump table "tablename" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `type' for "text":String

end
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it was the MySql version that was messing up the dump. I also removed the activerecord mysql adaptor
I changed my gemfile and the dump worked perfectly:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
```